# Qt signal slot button

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qpushbutton

I need to change my text in QLabel every time when I clicked in order to my info updates.
When I change the value of A, the value of B must change, too.
I have two button that can change values in two QLabel (value of A, value of B).

```
main.cpp:
Counter A, B;
QObject::connect(&A, &Counter::changeValue, &B, &Counter::setValue);
QObject::connect(&A, &Counter::changeValue, &B, &Counter::Increment);
QObject::connect(&A, &Counter::changeValue, &B, &Counter::Decrement );    


QObject::connect(Add, &QPushButton::clicked, &A, &Counter::clickedAdd(QLabel* obj));
QObject::connect(Sub, &QPushButton::clicked, &B, &Counter::clickedSub(QLabel* obj));


class Counter: public QObject{
private: 
int count;
public slots:
int Increment () {
count++;
emit changeValue(count);
}
int Decrement () {
count--;
emit changeValue(count);
}
void clickedAdd(QLabel* obj){
int new_count = Increment();
obj_label->setText(QString::number(new_count));_
}
void clickedSub(QLabel* obj){
int new_count = Deccrement();
obj_label->setText(QString::number(new_count));_
}
void setValue(int new_count){
m_count = new_count;
emit changeValue(new_count);
}
public signals:
void changeValue(int);
```

How can I change my text in two QLabel's? Because in this way it stays const - 0....
When I try to connect:

```
QObject::connect(Add, &QPushButton::clicked, &A, &Counter::clickedAdd(QLabel* obj));
```

It writes an error:
**Call to non-static member function without an object argument.**

But I pass the function an argument - QLabel*.

Comment: Please ask a question!

Comment: `QObject::connect(&A, &Counter::changeValue, &B, &Counter::Increment); QObject::connect(&A, &Counter::changeValue, &B, &Counter::Decrement );` This looks suspicious somehow: After every change of `Counter A` the counter `B` is incremented and decremented? Why?

Comment: The signals `clickedAdd()` and `clickedSub()` shouldn't be part of the `class Counter`. They should be part of that that uses the `class Counter`.

Comment: Concerning your question: `Counter::clickedAdd(QLabel* obj)` is just wrong in `QObject::connect()`. It expects a function or member function pointer (in your case - the latter) but you provide half of a declaration. The C++ compiler doesn't understand this and complains. Btw. the signature of `Counter::clickedAdd()` doesn't match the signature of the signal `QPushButton::clicked`. For this, you would need an adapter (a wrapper function or a lambda) but actually I believe your design is already wrong (like noted above).

Comment: @Scheff, it works good when I manually do it in the main.cpp:
`Add->clicked();
QDebud<< A.getValue(); // 1 `

Comment: _it works good when I manually do it in the main.cpp_ Things which are bad designed may work - but still are bad designed. ;-) (This is what you can see everyday in daily business.)

Comment: @Scheff sorry, 
`Add->clicked(); QDebud<< A.getValue(); // 1 `

Comment: I'm about to make a working sample but I will need a bit time to prepare it...

Comment: @Scheff, and you are right! That was a mistake to pass an argument in **clickedAdd(..)** in **connect**. But, based on this, how should I realize this?

Comment: @Scheff, Okay... I've been resolving this problem about second day...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming OP wants an application with

- two counters which can be incremented and decremented
- a GUI

  - displaying the counter values
  - buttons to increment/decrement the counters interactively.

From this requirement, I would derive the structure of the program:

- a class for the `Counter` (as already exposed by OP)
- a GUI.

For the latter, I often saw classes as well in numerous sample codes but I believe: for such a minimal GUI / application, this could even all be done in `main()` directly.

`testQCounter.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Qt header:
#include <QtWidgets>

// OPs Counter Class
class Counter : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT

  private:
    int count = 0;
  public slots:
    int Increment() {
      count++;
      emit changeValue(count);
      return count;
    }
    int Decrement() {
      count--;
      emit changeValue(count);
      return count;
    }
    int getValue() const { return count; }
    void setValue(int new_count) {
      count = new_count;
      emit changeValue(new_count);
    }
  signals:
    void changeValue(int);
};

#include "testQCounter.moc"

void setLabelValue(QLabel& qLbl, int value)
{
  qLbl.setText(QString::number(value));
}

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup data
  Counter a, b;
  // setup GUI
  QWidget qWinMain;
  qWinMain.setWindowTitle("Counter Sample");
  QGridLayout qGrid;
  QLabel qLblATitle("Counter A");
  qGrid.addWidget(&qLblATitle, 0, 0);
  QPushButton qBtnIncA("+");
  qGrid.addWidget(&qBtnIncA, 1, 0);
  QLabel qLblA;
  qLblA.setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
  qLblA.setFrameStyle(QLabel::Box);
  qGrid.addWidget(&qLblA, 2, 0);
  QPushButton qBtnDecA("-");
  qGrid.addWidget(&qBtnDecA, 3, 0);
  QLabel qLblBTitle("Counter B");
  qGrid.addWidget(&qLblBTitle, 0, 1);
  QPushButton qBtnIncB("+");
  qGrid.addWidget(&qBtnIncB, 1, 1);
  QLabel qLblB("");
  qLblB.setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
  qLblB.setFrameStyle(QLabel::Box);
  qGrid.addWidget(&qLblB, 2, 1);
  QPushButton qBtnDecB("-");
  qGrid.addWidget(&qBtnDecB, 3, 1);
  qWinMain.setLayout(&qGrid);
  qWinMain.show();
  setLabelValue(qLblA, a.getValue());
  setLabelValue(qLblB, b.getValue());
  // install signal handlers
  // connect clicked signal of buttons to counter a
  QObject::connect(&qBtnDecA, &QPushButton::clicked, &a, &Counter::Decrement);
  QObject::connect(&qBtnIncA, &QPushButton::clicked, &a, &Counter::Increment);
  // connect changeValue signal of counter a to a function
  QObject::connect(&a, &Counter::changeValue,
    [&](int value) { setLabelValue(qLblA, value); });
  // connect clicked signal of buttons to counter b
  QObject::connect(&qBtnDecB, &QPushButton::clicked, &b, &Counter::Decrement);
  QObject::connect(&qBtnIncB, &QPushButton::clicked, &b, &Counter::Increment);
  // connect changeValue signal of counter b to b function
  QObject::connect(&b, &Counter::changeValue,
    [&](int value) { setLabelValue(qLblB, value); });
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
Qt Version: 5.15.1
```

[image: Animated Snapshot of testQCounter.exe]

**Notes:**

1. Concerning the update of the counter value label:
   The signature of `QLabel::setText()` (the potential slot) is `void QLabel::setText(const QString&)`.
   The signature of the signal to connect is `void Counter::changeValue(int)`.
   Obviously, these signatures are not compatible.

   For convenience, I introduced a function

   ```
   void setLabelValue(QLabel& qLbl, int value)
   {
     qLbl.setText(QString::number(value));
   }
   ```

   but this doesn't fix the incompatibility because the function still has another parameter `QLabel&` which is not in the emitted signal.

   This is a very usual case and the very usual solution is to bind the resp. `QLabel` reference to the signal.
   It can be done most easily using a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

   When I first saw lambdas in C++, I found the syntax non-intuitive and somehow scaring.
   However, after having read the doc. and tutorials I got used to it, and today, I couldn't imagine to live without.
   I must admit before I learnt about lambdas I had to fiddle with `bind()` and `hide()` (in `gtkmm` with `sigc++`). This was a real nightmare…
2. `Counter` defines a `signal`. (I fixed the wrong syntax of OP.)

   To make this linking properly, I had to add some things:

   - `Q_OBJECT`
   - `#include "testQCounter.moc"`
   - support for the Qt moc in my build script.

   My build script is a Visual Studio project which I prepared with a `CMake` script.
   I had to extend my `CMakeLists.txt` for moc (as I usually build without moc).

   The `CMakeLists.txt` used to build the build script for `testQCounter.cc`:

   ```
   project(QCounter)

   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)

   set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

   find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

   set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
   set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
   include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")

   add_executable(testQCounter testQCounter.cc)
   target_link_libraries(testQCounter Qt5::Widgets)
   ```

---

For my production, I would use separate `class`es for the GUI stuff as well, of course.

So, considering that the sample has two counters with nearly identical GUIs, it may make sense to introduce a counter widget – `CounterEdit`.

`testQCounter2.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Qt header:
#include <QtWidgets>

// OPs Counter Class
class Counter : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT

  private:
    int count = 0;
  public slots:
    int Increment() {
      count++;
      emit changeValue(count);
      return count;
    }
    int Decrement() {
      count--;
      emit changeValue(count);
      return count;
    }
    int value() const { return count; }
    void setValue(int new_count) {
      count = new_count;
      emit changeValue(new_count);
    }
  signals:
    void changeValue(int);
};

#include "testQCounter2.moc"

class CounterEdit : public QWidget {
  private:
    Counter* pCounter = nullptr;
    QVBoxLayout qVBox;
    QLabel qLblTitle;
    QPushButton qBtnInc;
    QLabel qLblValue;
    QPushButton qBtnDec;

    QMetaObject::Connection connectionInc;
    QMetaObject::Connection connectionDec;
    QMetaObject::Connection connectionValue;

  public:
    CounterEdit(const QString& title, QWidget* pQParent = nullptr) :
      QWidget(pQParent),
      qLblTitle(title),
      qBtnInc("+"),
      qLblValue(""),
      qBtnDec("-")
    {
      qLblTitle.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
      qVBox.addWidget(&qLblTitle);
      qVBox.addWidget(&qBtnInc);
      qLblValue.setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);
      qLblValue.setFrameStyle(QLabel::Box);
      qVBox.addWidget(&qLblValue);
      qVBox.addWidget(&qBtnDec);
      setLayout(&qVBox);
    }

    virtual ~CounterEdit()
    {
      QObject::disconnect(connectionInc);
      QObject::disconnect(connectionDec);
      QObject::disconnect(connectionValue);
    }

    CounterEdit(const CounterEdit&) = delete;
    CounterEdit& operator=(const CounterEdit&) = delete;

    Counter* counter() { return pCounter; }
    const Counter* counter() const { return pCounter; }

    void updateValue();
    void updatevalue(int) { updateValue(); }

    void setCounter(Counter* pCounter);

};

void CounterEdit::updateValue()
{
  if (pCounter) {
    qLblValue.setText(QString::number(pCounter->value()));
  } else {
    qLblValue.setText(QString());
  }
}

void CounterEdit::setCounter(Counter* pCounter)
{
  QObject::disconnect(connectionInc);
  QObject::disconnect(connectionDec);
  QObject::disconnect(connectionValue);
  this->pCounter = pCounter;
  if (pCounter) {
    qLblValue.setText(QString::number(pCounter->value()));
    connectionInc
      = QObject::connect(&qBtnInc, &QPushButton::clicked, pCounter, &Counter::Increment);
    connectionDec
      = QObject::connect(&qBtnDec, &QPushButton::clicked, pCounter, &Counter::Decrement);
    connectionValue
      = QObject::connect(pCounter, &Counter::changeValue, this, &CounterEdit::updateValue);
  }
}

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup data
  Counter a, b;
  // setup GUI
  QWidget qWinMain;
  qWinMain.setWindowTitle("Counter Sample");
  QHBoxLayout qHBox;
  CounterEdit editA("Counter A:");
  qHBox.addWidget(&editA);
  CounterEdit editB("Counter B:");
  qHBox.addWidget(&editB);
  qWinMain.setLayout(&qHBox);
  qWinMain.show();
  editA.setCounter(&a);
  editB.setCounter(&b);
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
Qt Version: 5.15.1
```

[image: Snapshot of testQCounter2.exe]

**Notes:**

1. As data model and GUI are not anymore hardwired by design, I changed the management of the signal-slot connections a bit:

   - The connections are done on demand (in `CounterEdit::setCounter()`).
   - Connections are disconnected when not anymore needed.

   It's not strictly necessary to store the connections like I did in the sample.
   In Qt, a connection may be disconnected as well by providing signal and slot like in `connect()`.
   I don't like this for two reasons:

   1. I'm paranoid.
   2. This won't work for lambdas.
2. While the actual member function for update (`CounterEdit::updateValue()`) is parameter-less, I provided a second flavor (`CounterEdit::updateValue(int)`) which is just a wrapper.

   However, this 2<sup>nd</sup> flavor has an identical signature like `Counter::changeValue()` and, hence, can be used as slot without an adapter.

Comment: in  my realisation I only need to add one string of your code... - the realisation of connect with lambda! And it works! Thank you so much!