# QColorSpace: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5

I'm trying to run the imageviewer example from this website https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-imageviewer-example.html.
However, for some reason I don't seem to have QColorSpace.
I tried to include all of the possible libraries I thinnk I would need but still have no luck.
Is it my CMake file or do I need to somehow install QColorSpace?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(SAT_Solver LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# QtCreator supports the following variables for Android, which are identical to qmake Android variables.
# Check http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html for more information.
# They need to be set before the find_package(Qt5 ...) call.

#if(ANDROID)
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
#    if (ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a")
#        set(ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS
#            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libcrypto.so
#            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libssl.so)
#    endif()
#endif()

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets PrintSupport OpenGL Core Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Widgets PrintSupport OpenGL Core Gui REQUIRED)

if(ANDROID)
  add_library(SAT_Solver SHARED
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
    mainwindow.h
    mainwindow.ui
    ScribbleArea.cpp
    ScribbleArea.h
  )
else()
  add_executable(SAT_Solver
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
    mainwindow.h
    mainwindow.ui
    ScribbleArea.cpp
    ScribbleArea.h
    imageviewer.h
    imageviewer.cpp
  )
endif()
#qt5_add_resources(RC_SRC "resources/qml.qrc")
#qt5_add_resources(RC_SRC "/home/nalfredo/School/AutoSoftware/Project/QT/SAT_Solver/Resources.qrc")


target_link_libraries(SAT_Solver PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::PrintSupport
    ${QT_QTSVG_LIBRARY} Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::OpenGL Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Gui Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt5::Gui)
```

Comment: [QColorSpace](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolorspace.html) _was introduced in Qt 5.14._ So, you need a quite recent version of Qt for this. (Current release is 5.15.1.) Which one did you install on your side?

Comment: The sample seems to be made (or updated) quite recently as well. It's the first time I see a CMake build script which is already prepared for Qt6... :-)

Comment: How do I check my version on Qt Creator?

Comment: I'm not sure. The simplest way which comes in mind: Write a minimal program which does `qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;` in `main()` (like e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64611396/7478597)).

Comment: ...or google. I found [SO: How to find Version of Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40112592/7478597) :-)

Comment: qmake --version returned Qt 5.9.5. I guess I need to update. Thanks for the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find Version of Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058718/how-to-find-version-of-qt)

Comment: No. I followed the steps but the minimal program still says I'm running Qt 5.9.5 even after I installed Qt 5.15.1.

Comment: I now have Qt 5.15.1 running after purging my old Qt files. Now my code doesn't work for different reasons. Thanks for all of your help